# LM317 regulator with PNP pass transistor voltage drops when adding load

Tags: voltage-regulator, lm317

I'm trying to make a ~4V 2A regulator with the LM317.  It works with minimal load but when I increase the load the voltage drops instantly to 3.4V.  I'm not sure what's happening.

I'm trying to build something like this circuit:

[image: circuit I'm trying to implement]

I don't have the exact same components so my circuit actually looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBLBQw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another strange thing I've noticed is that when I add the load resistor, the sum of VCE + Vout is less than 24V (around 22V,) but the 24V power supply has it's own voltmeter and it marks 24V all the time, which shouldn't be possible as there's nowhere else between Vin and GND for those 2V to be. I thought it might be my cheap multimeter so I grabbed a better one but that one reads the same voltages.

Here are some photos of my setup:

[image: With no load]
[image: With load]

I'm aware the heatsink for the transistor is smaller than it should be, but this is just testing the circuit and it takes about 30s to heat up to where you can't touch it, the LM317 is always cold so it can't be thermal shutdown right?

I'm also aware that making a 2A voltage regulator on a breadboard is a bad idea, but again I am just trying to see if the circuit works.

From what I've seen of other questions it seems this can happen when you invert the pins, this is the pinout I'm following:

[image: Used pinout]

Edit: When i made the circuit on an universal board the regulator worked like it should.

Comment: _"I'm also aware that making a 2A voltage regulator on a breadboard is a bad idea"_- Yes, it is a bad idea. Breadboard contacts often have high resistance that causes trouble even at less than 1A. Connect your load and measure voltages across all components and the wires between them. What do you get?

Comment: Do you intend to operate this supply with no load? Your design violates LM317 minimum load current of 3.5 mA. Your design requires about 400 ohms load or less.

Comment: I intend to use it to supply a GSM module so minimal load is guaranteed also there's a fixed 1.2K resistor which @3.98V comes at 3.31mA so yeah, not minimal, I'll change it for a 1K so that's within requirements but I don't think the issue is there. When the load is essentially 10Ohm there's still a problem, so surely the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: Measure and see if there is a voltage difference between the different ground points on the circuit when the load is added. Maybe a high resistance somewhere.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Okay, so I was skeptic about the whole voltage falling on the wires but i measured just 1 and found 142mV across it, which is ludicrous, if I were to prototype this on an universal board would the circuit work as intended?

Comment: @James there's a 260mV difference between the ground rails at both sides of the breadboard

Comment: puh, this all says, from beginning to end "I'm going through a lot of trouble trying to make an ancient linear regulator fit a use case for a modern switch-mode regulator". Seriously, this is a dead end.

Comment: back of paper calculation: 20 V drop, 2 A = 40W waste heat. Your pass transistor should be instantly glowing red. It will hence change characteristics drastically, faster than you can look. This is all really a non-starter. 2A is totally feasible for a commercially available (non-amazon-junk-grade) switchmode power supplies.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it does not need 2A constant, just in "spikes" of no more than 10S with enough time for the transistor to cool off, also fine, a switching power supply would be a better choice, but at this point I'm just trying to figure out why i cant make a, how did you put it? "an ancient linear regulator" work, so I can, you know, learn something. My question wasn't how do i supply 4V 2A? my question is why is this circuit not working.

Comment: The answer is, as you've noticed, 1. uncertainty of qualiaty of contact due to breadboard, 2. instant overheating even under light load, 3. high resistance of breadboard, 4. insufficiently sized cabling; I'm really not convinced you can learn anything from such a system!

Comment: I understand you're less concerned about how to solve the technical problem, and I appreciate that. But using a badly compensated regulator with an external pass transistor under so many worsening factors - the lesson here is that you don't do that because the compounding problems lead to errors that can be incredibly hard to debug. I trust no circuit on a breadboard, ever, since I simply know that every single contact has a probability of being unreliable. Take the probability that a single contact works, say 98%, to the Nth power, where N is the number of breadboard contacts you make:

Comment: with only 25 contacts, you're already down to a "it works" probability of 60%; and that's assuming that only 2% of contacts are bad on a breadboard, which is *far* better than what I'd expect with the quality of material people typically deal with (there's better and less good breadboards, and cabling. I know exactly the board you're using – I have the same, for demonstration reasons. It's one of the rather bad ones.).

Comment: Regarding learning how things work: Hm. I don't buy that. You wouldn't build a large-current supply like that – the LM317 isn't used because it's a *good*  or *easy to understand* regulator, but because it was an *affordable* regulator, in late 1960s/1970s technology. If you want to *learn* about how to build a linear voltage regulator, an opamp, a MOSFET and a few feedback resistors would be significantly more meaningful – and by the way don't stand a bad chance of forming a better regulator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I used to believe that impedance of cables and contacts was negligible, which today I've learned is not, I appreciate that you're trying to teach me that  I'm going about the problem the wrong way and that I've brushed off too much stuff as unimportant, but and I don't want to sound insufferable but here we go anyway I take issue with the way you initially tried to convey that information.

Comment: I'm sorry if I hurt you! That wasn't my intention!

Comment: @MarcusMüller let's just leave it there, Main takeaway is: Prototype boards are not great for prototyping, Also yeah my breadboard is terrible it costed my 100 Ars which I'll let you google the conversion s̶o̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶g̶o̶o̶d̶ ̶l̶a̶u̶g̶h̶ so you can appreciate just how cheap it is.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The issue was indeed the breadboard, cables had drops of ~140mV when the circuit was loaded. I made the circuit on an universal board and it works now. Since you were the first (but by no means the last) to bring this up to my attention maybe you'd like to post it as an answer so I can accept to wrap this up bow and all

Comment: 100 ARS = 1.04 USD = 0.88 EUR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another strange thing I've noticed is that when I add the load
> resistor, the sum of VCE + Vout is less than 24V (around 22V,) but the
> 24V power supply has it's own voltmeter and it marks 24V all the
> time... When i made the circuit on an universal board the regulator
> worked like it should.

This suggests the problem was... your solderless breadboard! Cheap breadboards often have high contact resistance and a low maximum current rating. I have seen significant voltage drops even at currents well below 1 A on breadboards I bought from eBay, whereas a board I have had for 30 years is much better (even after I partially melted it passing too much current through the power rails one time).

For currents over 1 A it pays to solder the connections, and use thicker wire to carry the current when using [stripboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard) too.

Comment: It would be nice if it was easier to know what breadboards were good and which ones were bad... You never see them with contact resistance ratings or anything.

Comment: @Hearth perhaps insertion force? My old breadboard is often quite hard to push thick wires into, whereas the new ones feel loose. You could measure the contact strip thickness with calipers to estimate current handling and spring tension, or of course just pass a current though it and measure the voltage drop.